# How do I populate a spinner instead of a textview? not sure where to start

Tags: java, android, json, spinner

I am able to parse a JSON array into a textview but want to populate a spinner instead. Currently I'm using the following code to parse JSON into a textview. Ideally I want to have a spinner that lists the results by "name" and puts "volume", "fullweight" and "emptyweight" into seperate text views based on the item selected. This is my first attempt at including a spinner in an app and I can't work out where to start.

```
public void getJSON(){
    String url = "https://example.com/DBReadJSON.php";
    JsonRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("bottles");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject bottles = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String Name = bottles.getString("name");
                            int vol = bottles.getInt("volume");
                            int full = bottles.getInt("fullweight");
                            int empty = bottles.getInt("emptyweight");
                            mTextViewResult.append(Name + ", " + vol + ", " + full +", " + empty + "\n");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    mQueue.add(request);
}
```

I Realise this is probably a stupid question, and I've gone about parsing the JSON entirely wrong. Sorry about that. I'd be grateful to be even pointed in the direction of a tutorial on how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Code taken from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_spinner_control.htm.

```
 class AndroidSpinnerExampleActivity extends Activity implements  OnItemSelectedListener{

   Spinner spinner;
   ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;

   List<String> categories;

   public void update(String add){
      categories.add(add);
      
      dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
      
      dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
      spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      
      // Spinner element
      spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
      
      // Spinner click listener
      spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
      
      // Spinner Drop down elements
      categories = new ArrayList<String>();
      categories.add("Automobile");
      categories.add("Business Services");
      categories.add("Computers");
      categories.add("Education");
      categories.add("Personal");
      categories.add("Travel");
      
      // Creating adapter for spinner
      dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
      
      // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
      dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
      
      // attaching data adapter to spinner
      spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
   }
   
   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      // On selecting a spinner item
      String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
      
      // Showing selected spinner item
      Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }
}
```

This is more or less how to setup a spinner and update/add contents in. All you do is call update(add) with the value you want to add to it.